# Intuitive explanation how scalar multiplication of vectors works

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry

**How can scalar multiplication of two vectors be intuitively explained in geometrical terms?** What does it mean geometrically that the scalar multiplication of two vectors has certain value?

Specifically, I'm asking in relation to the calculation of a distance of certain point from a plane.

Given a following plane:
 $$A(x-x_0)+B(y-y_0) + C(z-z_0)=0$$
the distance from a point:
$$P = (a, b, c)$$
would be 
$$\frac{|[(a-x_0), (b-y_0), (c-z_0)]\circ[A, B, C]|}{||[A, B,C]||}$$
I don't understand how does it work though. Hence the question.

---

**EDIT**

Same thing applies to e.g. calculation of the distance of a line from another line, so probably a general question is:

**How does projection work?**

as the equation given above is a projection of $$[(a-x_0), (b-y_0), (c-z_0)]$$ through $$[A, B, C]$$